# How to make certain word clickable for action like modal popup in UITextView Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm developing an educational app and I want users to be able to click on certain key terms and a modal popup will appear with the definition. I'm new to Swift so I'll try to explain my methodology so far, as I'm lost on what to search up to work at my solution.

I believe that I have to use a UITextView but I'm not sure how to pin point certain words and have them be clickable as if they were like a UIButton where I can bring up a new screen with it. Here is an example of exactly what I'm looking for below. Also, what type of screen popup is shown where you can drag it down to close?

Thank you so much for any help. Just looking for the right direction.

[image: Clickable word, popup with definition.]

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented in my current project, you can translate this to swift.

```
  NSString* description = @"Hello world";
  NSString* term_str = @"world"
  NSString* detail = [NSString stringWithFormat:description,term_str];

  NSMutableAttributedString *linkStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:detail attributes:nil];
  [linkStr addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:NSLocalizedString(@"here_is_link_you_want_to_open", @"") range:[detail rangeOfString:term_str]];
  [linkStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:[detail rangeOfString:term_str]];
  _descriptionLabel.attributedText = linkStr;

  _descriptionLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [_descriptionLabel addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(your_function:)]];
```

Implement your funciton **your_function** hope this work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don’t have any experience with Objective C either, but I think it’s a head start. I’m guessing NSString is what I need to get familiar with? And then I can connect the GestureRecognizer to open a new page?

Comment: Yes you need to make attributed string, for more information related to attributed string check apple doc, after that you need to make your text view clickable by adding gestures

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
       //Your code
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do This By in few Step :

1.Add Tap gesture For Get The specific Word
2.Use UITextView Delegate method : textViewDidChangeSelection
3.Use prepare Segue Method For pass text String to presening ViewController.

1.

`let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnTextView(_:)))
textView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)`

tapgesture:

```
@objc private final func tapOnTextView(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        let point = tapGesture.location(in: textView)
        if let detectedWord = getWordAtPosition(point) {
            print(detectedWord)
        }
    }
```

2.Use Delegate Method

`textView.delegate = self`

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "modelSeg", sender: self)
  }
```

3. Use Prepare Segue Method to pass specific word to your modal (Viewcontroller)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegindentifire" {
        let modelVC = segue.destination as! ModelVC
         modalVC.word = word
    }
}
```